# Existe limite no angular para request post?

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma requisição post via $http no angular, e quando meu back-end retorna uma string json muito grande ele não carrega, isto me faz pensar se existe alguma configuração que limite um request que retorne uma string muito grande.

Meu back-end é em PHP.

Comment: é um `HTTP/GET`?

Comment: Você já viu o post_max_size no PHP.ini?

Comment: Perdão pela ignorância, mas é um POST, e em resultado a este post que eu faço, que nada mais é do que passar um id qualquer para meu back-end, ele gera uma "mega string" e retorna para meu front-end tratar.

Comment: De qual tamanho mais ou menos estamos falando, em KB?

Comment: 8947 caracteres. Não sei exatamente quantos KB tem.

Comment: O que acontece é que o AngularJS não é bom para renderizar listas muito grandes com o ng-repeat, tenta paginar os seus dados ou utilizar o infinite scrolling.